# Updating objects in an array (matching by value)

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

Have first array (a) and second with updated values (b). Need to update matching by IDs objects and get result array (c). How can I make it simple and fast?

```
let a = [
    { id: 1, activated: '0' },
    { id: 2, activated: '0' },
    { id: 3, activated: '0' },
    { id: 4, activated: '0' },
  ]
let b = [
    { id: 2, activated: '1' },
    { id: 3, activated: '1' },
  ]
//Result array:
c = [ 
  { id: 1, activated: '0' },
  { id: 2, activated: '1' },
  { id: 3, activated: '1' },
  { id: 4, activated: '0' },
]
```

Comment: Do you want to merge the arrays ordering them by ID?

Comment: What did you try? Please read topics at https://StackOverflow.com/help for more info about requirements for asking questions on SO.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend you to create an object where keys are the ids for fast access.

With the newly created object you can access the specific objects from `b` using the `id` as key and update the objects.

Finally, get the array `c` using the function `Object.values`.

This is assuming that `b` has ids that exist in `a`.

```js
let a = [    { id: 1, activated: '0' },    { id: 2, activated: '0' },    { id: 3, activated: '0' },    { id: 4, activated: '0' }]
let b = [    { id: 2, activated: '1' },    { id: 3, activated: '1' }];
let newA = a.reduce((a, {id, ...rest}) => ({...a, ...{[id]: {id, ...rest}}}), {});

b.forEach(({id, activated}) => newA[id].activated = activated);

let c = Object.values(newA);
console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Great, Thank you!

Comment: @МаксимЮрченко yw!

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), then foreach object, you can use [Array.find](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) to check if it exist in arrayB by ID and return if it does.

```
let a = [
    { id: 1, activated: '0' },
    { id: 2, activated: '0' },
    { id: 3, activated: '0' },
    { id: 4, activated: '0' },
];

let b = [
    { id: 2, activated: '1' },
    { id: 3, activated: '1' },
];

const c = a.map(e => {
    let newValue = b.find(n => e.id === n.id);

    if (!!newValue) {
        return newValue;
    }

    return e;
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This is how I would approach it:

```js
function mergeArray(...toMerge) {
  let output = {};
  toMerge.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(item => {
      output[item.id] = item;
    });
  });
  return Object.values(output);
}

let a = [
    { id: 1, activated: '0' },
    { id: 2, activated: '0' },
    { id: 3, activated: '0' },
    { id: 4, activated: '0' },
  ];
let b = [
    { id: 2, activated: '1' },
    { id: 3, activated: '1' },
  ];

console.dir(mergeArray(a, b)) // can merge n-number of arrays.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
let c = a.map( aObj => {
  let found = b.find(bObj => bObj.id === aObj.id);
    if(found) return found;
    else return aObj;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a map of the second array, keyed by `id`, and then when you make a copy of `a` objects into `c`, use that map to merge matching `b` objects into them.

```js
let a = [{ id: 1, activated: '0' },{ id: 2, activated: '0' },{ id: 3, activated: '0' },{ id: 4, activated: '0' }]
let b = [{ id: 2, activated: '1' },{ id: 3, activated: '1' }];

let map = new Map(b.map(o => [o.id, o]));
let c = a.map(o => ({...o, ...map.get(o.id)}));

console.log(c);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Building a hash from the ids of array a. Iterate over array b by looking in the hash for the index b.id, if found actualisize in a with the founded index the property activated. Otherwise (in example id: 5) there don't exists in the old array a for this id an entry so create a new one and actualisize the hash.

```js
let a = [
    { id: 1, activated: '0' },
    { id: 2, activated: '0' },
    { id: 3, activated: '0' },
    { id: 4, activated: '0' },
  ];
let b = [
    { id: 2, activated: '1' },
    { id: 3, activated: '1' },
    { id: 5, activated: '0' },
  ];

let hash = a.flatMap(el => el.id);

b.forEach(elem => {
    index = hash.indexOf(elem.id);
    if (index!=-1) 
        a[index].activated=elem.activated;
     else {
        a.push(elem);
        hash.push(elem.id);
     }
});
  
console.log(a);
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```js
let a = [{
    id: 1,
    activated: '0'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    activated: '0'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    activated: '0'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    activated: '0'
  },
]
let b = [{
    id: 2,
    activated: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    activated: '1'
  },
]
//Result array:
c = [{
    id: 1,
    activated: '0'
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    activated: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    activated: '1'
  },
  {
    id: 4,
    activated: '0'
  },
]

let result = a.map(e => {
  let p = b.find(be => be.id === e.id)
  if (p) e.activated = p.activated;
  return e
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: can anybody explain why this would be not ideal solution? im curious to know about perf optimisation.

Comment: Not my downvote, but `find` represents a loop, and so you have a nested loop giving a total time complexity of *O(n²)*, while this can be done in linear time.